# What's the best RDBMS structure to model an abstract "compatibility" between records in the same table

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have a table of Widgets. Some Widgets are compatible with others, via an abstract grouping: All Widgets in a group are compatible with all others, though there is no concrete definition of the grouping itself. In practice, when adding a new "Widget B", a user could mark its compatibility with existing "Widget A", and then business logic would ensure the proper data structure to express compatibility with all other Widgets that already share compatibility with Widget A.

My current concept:

```
Widget (widget_id PK, name)  
Compatibility (compat_id PK)  
Widget_Compatibility (widget_id FK, compat_id FK)
```

where Compatibility is a completely arbitrary object with no attributes, but must have one or more related Widgets through the link table.

The question is: are there other common (or more efficient) patterns for representing this concept?

(My first SO post, so thanks in advance for your patience)

Comment: You can have "pairs" of compatibility.  However, that requires a recursive CTE to figure out the groupings.

Comment: Each compatibility group is/identiifes a (sub)type of widget. Google re SQL/DB subtyping/inheritance/polymorphism. A faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Hi - given your statement "All Widgets in a group are compatible with all others" is it true to say that a widget can only be in 1 compatibility group?

Comment: @NickW yes, only one Compatibility group is possible per widget (or zero)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add a "Compatibility Group" field to your widget table? When you want to indicate that 2 widgets are compatible then if either widget already has this field populated then use the value in that field, otherwise generate a new value and update the field on both widget records

Comment: After thinking and reading a lot about polymorphism, it occurred to me that, since the only actual type attribute for a compatibility group is its identity, I could solve this exactly how you describe, with the arbitrary values provided by a sequence, and/or stored as single-column rows in a table to enforce ref integrity. Thanks to all for getting my brain juices flowing and confirming that I'm on the right track!